# how to publish .ipa produced by TFS2015 with Cordova Build task

Tags: cordova, build, task

I am trying to publish the ipa (ios application build with cordova) but I cannot copy it from the Mac to an external server.

What I have done:

- Created a Cordova application with VS2015
- Added the source code to TFS2015
- Created a team build with Cordova Build task that is executed on a mac

Everything works fine and the ipa is produced on the mac in the following folder : **AgentFolder_work\3\s\platforms\ios\build\device\my.ipa**
Nothing is output to **AgentFolder_work\3\a**
I have the following message in the log: *Skipping packaging. Detected cordova-ios verison that auto-creates ipa.*
My understanding is the message above indicates why nothing is output (I may be wrong).

What is the missing step for copying the ipa out of the Mac so that it can be used to be deployed to developers iPad ?

Comment: Seems like your .ipa is getting generated fine.  If that's the case, I think you need to add a "Publish Build Artifacts" step to your build, which takes the output of the build and puts it on a separate server somewhere. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/steps/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts

Comment: Thx Steve, "Publish Build Artifacts" will publish from what's in _work\3\a\ folder (for my understanding), but there is nothing there. The workaround I found is to use a 'Shell Script' task to copy the IPA to a remote server. I mounted my remote server on my mac and the copy (with cp source destination) works in Terminal but an extra trailing character is added when I execute the same command with sh on the mac (and through TFS build). I'll post the full workaround once it will work.

Comment: This is the completed workaround I have found: 1-map a shared folder from mac to a windows machine shared folder. 2-create a .sh shell script containing 'cp platforms/ils/build/device/xxx.ipa ~/../../Volumes/WindowsSharedFolderName/xxxtarget.ipa' at the root of the project (so in the source) control. 3-after the 'Build Cordova' task in build steps add a 'Shell Script' with Script Path=Script.sh (which has been created at step 2). With this I now have the ipa available out of the mac. Hope this will help others.